# Prepare gremlin query before specifying to query edges or vertices

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop, janusgraph

I am using janusgraph to develop my java backend. I want to prepare my query on the elements regardless being edges or vertices before specifying to query edges or vertices this will give me flexibility in my code when it comes to building the query dynamically on the properties.

So my question is,**Can I use gremlin to prepare the query before starting from V or E ?**

For example if I want to apply the same query to Edges and vertices I will write:

```
g.V().has("p1","v1").has("p2","v1").has("p3","v1")
g.E().has("p1","v1").has("p2","v1").has("p3","v1")
```

What I am seeking for is something like this

```
gt = grahTraversal.has("p1","v1").has("p2","v1").has("p3","v1")
gt.E()
gt.V()
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the code like this(JAVA)

```
import static org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.dsl.graph.__.*;

...

GraphTraversal g = __.has("p1","v1").has("p2","v1").has("p3","v1");
resultG = grahTraversal.E().where(g);
resultG = grahTraversal.V().where(g);
```

The details can be found in official [documents](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/3.3.3/reference/#using-where-with-match) .

Comment: This souds good I trieds it but I am building the .has conditions using a loop dynamically but I am getting this error
`Traversal strategies are complete and traversal can no longer be modulated.` Any ideas ?

Comment: I have found a way to clone the traversal from another one and that solved the problem in the first comment .
`__.start().asAdmin().clone()`